# Boost variant ambiguous construction

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

The Boost Variant documentation says the following of the constructor that accepts arbitrary type:

```
template<typename T> variant(T & operand);
```

- **Requires:** T must be unambiguously convertible to one of the bounded types (i.e., T1, T2, etc.).

The same is true of the constructors accepting `const T&` and `T&&`. So I expect that the following code won't compile:

```
boost::variant<std::string, bool> v = "text";
```

But the code compile, and `v` becomes a bool, which is something I definitely did not want. Of course the solution is to wrap the string literal in a `std::string` constructor. My question is:

1. Why does this code compile?
2. How does it choose the type (as `const char*` is convertible to both `std::string` and `bool`)?

Comment: Of course, in c++14 use `v = "test"s;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, user-defined conversions lose overload resolution process to standard conversions.

There is a built-in conversion from `const char` pointers to `bool` which is preferred over the non-built-in conversion from `const char *` to `std::string` (e.g. see [Implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)).

`std::string`, while part of the standard library, is not a built-in type so its conversion constructors are considered only after conversions to built-in types.

Some references:

- [Why does the compiler choose bool over string for implicit typecast of L""?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/316181/3235496)
- [Why is my overloaded C++ constructor not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3425015/3235496)