# boost::variant construction weirdness - its ctor accepts everything

Tags: c++, type-conversion, boost-variant

The subject is already touched in this [boost-variant-ambiguous-construction question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802885/boost-variant-ambiguous-construction).

But my issue is not with types convertible to each other, but with completely unrelated types.

Simplified example:

```
// types not related in any way
class A {};
class B {};
class C {};
class D {};

using ABC_variant = boost::variant<A,B,C>;
using D_optional = boost::optional<D>;
```

The issue was related with the fact that optional on some type was not printable. But, completely unrelated output operator for some variant was trying to accept this boost::optional type (D_optional).

See:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const ABC_variant&)
{
    return os << "ABC";
}

int main() {
    D_optional dopt;
    std::cout << dopt;
}
```

You can see on [ideone](http://ideone.com/jhMU8z) - plenty of compilers errors saying that it does not know what do you want to print `bool` or `ABC_variant` and in case of `ABC_variant` it does not know how to convert `D_optional` to `ABC_variant`. As I understand that boost::optional is convertible to `bool` and first alternative is correct I have no idea why it tries to use `ABC_variant` conversion...

Furthermore I simplified this example even more and give up with boost::optional:

```
int main() {
    D d;
    std::cout << d;
}
```

Now, it does not have "`bool` alternative" and just complaining that it tries to construct `ABC_variant` from `D`:

> prog.cpp:23:15:   required from here
>   /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1591:38: error: no matching
>   function for call to 'boost::variant::initializer::initialize(void*, D&)'
>                  initializer::initialize(

This **here** is ostream operator for `ABC_variant`.

Of course I know that writing ostream operator for D/D_opt will solve the issue - but the problem is with diagnostic: if boost::variant did not accept any type as argument for its constructor, the compiler would tell me simple true - not this bunch of misleading sentences...

I doubt it is in such way by design - maybe there is some fixes ongoing?

*Fortunately I and ideone uses the same compiler and boost: gcc4.9 and boost1.58.*

Comment: `optional` is only *contextually* convertible to `bool`. As to `variant`, that constructor should be constrained, but isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created [boost ticket for this problem](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11602). Just to clarify what is the real problem:

Real problem is with this boost.variant "converting" constructor accepting any type - there is no restriction, even so natural like that argument type should be convertible to any of this boost.variant instantiation types:

```
template <typename T>
variant(const T& operand)
{
    convert_construct(operand, 1L);
}
```

My proposed solution can be something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename ...C>
struct IsAnyOf;

template <typename T, typename ...C>
struct IsAnyOf<T,T,C...> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct IsAnyOf<T> : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, typename C1, typename ...C>
struct IsAnyOf<T,C1,C...> : IsAnyOf<T, C...> {};

template <typename T, 
      typename EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<IsAnyOf<VariantType...>::value>::type>
    variant(const T& operand)
```

But for now - the only solution is not to create any non template function accepting instantiation of boost::variant. So either create function template or aggregate instantiation of boost::variant in some struct type.

So either this:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,ABC_variant>::value, std::ostream&>::type
operator << (std::ostream& os, const T&)
{
    return os << "ABC";
}
```

Or something like this:

```
struct ABC_variant
{
   boost::variant<A,B,C> v;
   ABC_variant(const A&);
   ABC_variant(const B&);
   ABC_variant(const C&);
};
```

---

**The [issue](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11602) is fixed in boots.1.62**